# Max of several variables in excel list in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list like the one below but for >100k rows. I want to find the max value for each letter in the list. Need a solution in vba rather than a worksheet function.

```
letter    value
A.        100
B.        200
C.        300
A.        250
B.        150
A.        200
C.        350
```

Comment: Is you data tabular like you have mentioned in your question?

Comment: would be an easy one for a database. With pure Excel it's a little bit more effort. But in general: create a list of letters without duplicates. After you have that you can use the Max() function. So in general it should be possible to solve without VBA

Comment: Apologies for poor formatting in original; yes tabular. Ideally i would just use Access however need a excel based solution!

Comment: Why not just use a pivot table. Will take about 30 seconds. Drag `letter` to the row field area, `value` to the values area and set the summary function to max.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is by using `Dictionary` object. Below is the code presenting how to achieve it (comments inside the code):

```
Public Sub findMaxValues()
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim row As Long
    Dim letter As String
    Dim value As Double
    '---------------------------------------------------------
    Dim varKey As Variant
    '---------------------------------------------------------


    'Read the data into array (for better performance).
    'I assumed that data starts in the cell A1 of the currently active worksheet. If not,
    'change the code below properly.
    Set wks = Excel.ActiveSheet
    data = wks.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion


    Set dict = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare


    'Iterate through all the rows of the array (start from the second row to skip headers).
    For row = LBound(data, 1) + 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        letter = VBA.Trim(data(row, 1))
        value = data(row, 2)

        'For each row check if the letter assigned to this row has been already added to the dictionary.
        If dict.Exists(letter) Then

            'If letter has been added before, check if the current value is greater than the previous one
            'and override it, if it is.
            If value > dict.Item(letter) Then
                dict.Item(letter) = value
            End If

        Else

            'If letter has not been added to the dictionary before, add it with the current value.
            Call dict.Add(letter, value)
        End If

    Next row



    'At this point, we have dictionary with as many items as many letters are in the worksheet.
    'Each item has a letter as a key and this letter's max value as a value.
    'To check it, let's print it in Immediate window.
    For Each varKey In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print varKey & ": " & dict.Item(varKey)
    Next varKey


End Sub
```

Comment: Looks a good way of doing it if VBA is required and nicely commented +1

Comment: Exactly what i was after! Thanks

Comment: Clean method for the dictionary object. I had forgotten details, But I remember it was fast as flash, even with huge datasets. Thanks for the remainder.

Answer (score 2):

**ADO approach**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim objAdCon, objAdRs, strSQL

    Set objAdCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    With objAdCon
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\test.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"""
        .Open
    End With

    strSQL = "select letter, max(value) from [Sheet1$] group by letter"
    Set objAdRs = objAdCon.Execute(strSQL)

    Sheet1.Range("D1").CopyFromRecordset objAdRs
End Sub
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: So much more elegant than the Dictionary approach. However it requires that the workbook was saved at least once.